# ¿Por qué salta directamente al tercer printf?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo práctica de  C. El código funciona pero NO correctamente, me salta directamente a el tercer printf.

Necesito que arranque pidiendo que "Ingrese la cantidad de votantes"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <conio.h>

#include <locale.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

setlocale(LC_ALL,"spanish");

long int votante, n_votante, sumaCandA, sumaCandB, sumaCandC, minVotos, maxVotos, difVotos;

float porcentaje_A, porcentaje_B, porcentaje_C;

char voto, minCand, maxCand, candidato;


//inicializacion

n_votante=1;

minVotos=9999;

maxVotos=-1;

sumaCandA=0;

sumaCandB=0;

sumaCandC=0;

maxCand='x';

minCand='x';

//Proceso 

printf("Ingrese la cantidad de votantes:\n\n");

n_votante>votante;

while (n_votante<=votante){
    
    printf("Ingrese el candidato a votar\n Candidato A= Coqui,\nCandidato B= Peppo\nCandidato C= Nikitch):\n");

}
    

//solicitud del voto
    
do {        

    printf("Ingrese el candidato a votar\n Candidato A= Coqui,\n Candidato B= Peppo\n Candidato C= Nikisch:\n");       

    fflush(stdin);
    
    voto=getchar();
        
    voto=toupper(voto);    

} while ((voto=!'A') && (voto!='B') && (voto!='C'));
```

---

Lo que necesito es que funcione la primer parte. Porque de otro modo no puedo calcular nada....       :'C
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor, actualiza tu pregunta, en vez de adjuntar imágenes introduce directamente el código utilizado! Gracias!

Comment: Necesitas solicitar información con la función scanf, la linea 27 no hace nada.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta leer la cantidad de votantes, modifica así en tu primer printf

```
//Proceso 

printf("Ingrese la cantidad de votantes:\n\n");
scanf(%d, &votante);
```

ya que en ningun momento pides que el usuario te ingrese un valor

Comment: Posiblemente esta respuesta sea reportada por baja calidad. Explica un poco más el código. No es necesario que la respuesta sea extensa. Por otro lado, una cantidad es un número y `getchar` lee un solo carácter. Lo que necesitas es `scanf`.